# $n$ is a natural number such that $n^5$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n$ is a natural number such that $n^5$ is odd then which of the following is true?

$1.n$ is odd

$2.n^3$ is odd

$3.n^4$ is even.

$3$ is always true as any number multiplied by even times it will become an even number. am I right?

Comment: $1^4 = 1$ is odd. $n^k$, if $n$ is odd, is the product of $k$ odd numbers, and if $n$ is even, the product of $k$ even numbers.

Comment: if you are allowed to use modulo calculations you can just check what happens when $n=0$ and what happens when $n=1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: An odd number is any number of the form $2n + 1$ for $n$ an integer. So the product of two odd numbers: $(2n+1)(2m+1) = 2(2nm + n + m) + 1$ is odd.

Second: If the product $ab$ is even then it is divisible by $2$. (Since $2$ is prime) that means that $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $2$. So $a$ or $b$ has to be even.

That is: $ab$ is even if and only if $a$ is even or $b$ is even.

Or: $ab$ is odd if and only if $a$ is odd and $b$ is odd.

So if $n^5$ is odd, then $n$ is ***_*__*_*_** and so $n^3$ is ***_*__*_*_** and $n^4$ is ***_*__*_*_**.

Comment: $n$ is odd and $n^3$ is oddddddddddddddddd

Comment: @miosaki: good job.

Answer (score 1):

Even number multiplied by even number is even. Odd number multiplied by odd number is odd. So if $x$ is odd then for all integer a, $x^a$ is odd

Comment: Non-negative integers $a$; $3^{-1}$ is not odd.